# php: how to use strip_tags with UTF8?

Tags: php, utf-8

```
echo $src;
```

gives:

```
4960 MALMEDY
```

Then when I apply `echo strip_tags($src);`

gives me:

```
4960Â MALMEDY
```

The SPACE was replaced by Â character:

What Do I do wrong ?

It looks that if I use

`$src = utf8_decode($src);` strip_tags works correctly.

Any rule I should know when to apply utf8_decode ?

Comment: What is the original character in there? It isn't space. There is something 'invisible'

Comment: Are you looking at this in a browser? Look at the source then. Are there any HTML tags in that string or not?

Comment: I look in browser AND source code of course !

Comment: Show us `bin2hex($src)` then, or figure out yourself what hidden bytes are in there based on that.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
   $text_top = strip_tags(trim(html_entity_decode($str,   ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'), "\xc2\xa0"));
```

Comment: did not work: what worked is: utf8_decode
$src = utf8_decode($src);
I am totally lost now on how to handle utf8 or not utf8 documents

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```php
header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
```